# jQuery $(document).ready and ASP.NET MVC Partial

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have quite a few partials in my application, and some of them need to do some jQuery goodness at $(document).ready time.

The problem is, if I put the $(document).ready directly into a script block for the partial, then this gets overridden if another partial does the same thing.

It seems a solution where the various $(document).ready tidbits are gathered up and then included in a single $(document).ready instance is needed.

Is there a defined way to do this already?

Answer (score 12):

well, just plain old never mind!

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready

Comment: Maybe you should set this as answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

is there anything wrong with doing something like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Myapp...SearchResultsViewModel>" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('partial is ready.');
    });
</script>

<h1>This is my <%: Model.name %> partial view</h1>
```