# asp.net mvc multiple partial view document ready is not called

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have two self contained views that loads the required data in their respective document ready functions.

I have a home page where I now want to show the two views. I am adding them as partial views but the issue is only the first partial view's document ready is triggered no matter what the order is. Below is the sample code of the Home page. Only the task view's document ready is called. If I reverse the order, the activity view document ready is called but not the task view.

In one of the links [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312718/jquery-document-ready-and-asp-net-mvc-partial) I found a suggestion to create a common js file but I want to maintain the separation of logic and let each view do its own work.

```
<div style="width:300px">
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Task/Index.cshtml")
}
</div>
<div style="width:300px">
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Activity/Index.cshtml")
}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your partials please?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `$(document).ready()` events should not be a problem, [see this article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready). The issue is probably somewhere else, it is probably worth checking to see if you are duplicating element ids within your partials or javascript variables within the jquery as this could cause the second block of jquery to fail.

Comment: sorry for the wrong vote. I setup two blank partial views with alert message in their respective document ready. It works as expected. Will check the ids and java variables.

Comment: @Pinakin - no problem, hope you find the issue. If the code in questioin is not too verbose you can always edit your question to show it if you require any more help.